# HP Laptop says "Enter Power On Password " with a key like picture

Tags: boot, bios

My HP laptop is asking for Power On Password that I never setup.  How do I get around the password and how do I remove this setting so the problem does not recur?

Comment: related: [How do I deal with an HP laptop with lost power-on password?](http://superuser.com/q/250789/172747)

Comment: If the cmos password reset does not work, enter a wrong password 3 times, it should generate a code, post the code and I will generate you a master password.